# Installing Solum for Openstack/Devstack

Tags: ubuntu, installation, openstack, devstack

I've been trying to install Solum locally (first on Windows, then on Ubuntu) since about 3 weeks ago, with no success.

There have been four distinct attempts I've tried:

A. [Installing m2 demo of Solum](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Solum/solum_m2_demo) - installation seems succesful, but fails on the last step - ie. connecting via browser. VagrantBox's port 9001 is forwarded, the route is pingable, but both Firefox and Google Chrome respond with "Unable to connect". Just-in-case changing 192.168.78.0 to 192.168.76.0 didn't help.

Interestingly, inspecting the virtual machine with vagrant ssh shows that "solum is not a recognized command".

B. [On Ubuntu](http://solum.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install/index.html#for-a-development-installation-use-devstack) - fatal error right by the start (no repository). I can't find a way to fix that line via any config files.

```
user@user:~/Inzynierka/solum/contrib/devstack$ sh setup_devstack.sh
Checking for Docker
Getting Solum Code
Cloning into '/home/user/solum'...
remote: Counting objects: 11080, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (5272/5272), done.
remote: Total 11080 (delta 7927), reused 8395 (delta 5518)
Receiving objects: 100% (11080/11080), 1.64 MiB | 1.59 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (7927/7927), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Getting devstack Code
Cloning into '/home/user/devstack'...
fatal: https://git.openstack.org/cgit/openstack-dev/devstack.git/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?
Setting up devstack for Solum
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/home/user/devstack/lib’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/home/user/devstack/extras.d’: No such file or directory
Starting devstack
setup_devstack.sh: 27: cd: can't cd to /home/user/devstack
Finished!
```

C. Installing the development environment (from solum's readthedocs dot org - can't post link because of two-link limit for users with less than 10 reputation). Once again:

```
fatal: remote error: access denied or repository not exported: /stackforge/solum
```

D. Installing solum separately on devstack - I can install devstack with no problem, but I have no idea what to do after that. All the documentation says about it: (again from solum's readthedocs dot org - two-link limit)

```
 TODO add docs here on how to install on different distros like:

     debian
     redhat
     suse
     ubuntu
```

Am I doing something wrong? At this point I'm starting to wonder if Solum has been discontinued or if it's not ready for use yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using vagrant repo on Ubuntu? (https://github.com/rackerlabs/vagrant-solum-dev). This is the preferred approach.

For setting up Solum directly on Devstack, you will need to set up Solum specific files within Devstack. Recently I have submitted a patch to update the setup script (https://review.openstack.org/#/c/230222/)

If you still run into issues, find me on Solum's IRC channel and I will help you out.

Comment: The first link - creating the VM via `vagrant up devstack` results in terminal being flooded with errors ending in `Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'`. The VM is installed, is accessible via `vagrant ssh` but still doesn't understand `openstack` or `solum` commands. Will try the updated setup script if I can't find a fix for that.

Comment: The first approach worked after I added `config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|  v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"] end` after `Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|` in Vagrantfile, which forced Vagrant to use host's DNS settings.

Comment: @Dragomok I have updated Solum installation instructions recently. You can find them here: https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Solum/solum-development-setup